# Ads Cash coin is really based on Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain

### There is a new crypto currency started last month known as Ads.Cash (https://ads.cash/) with following "About" Section.

### "AdsCash is the multifunctional next generation crypto currency for the Adworld based on Ethereum blockchain using cutting edge smart contract feature."

Many people are treating this as another BitCoin and can change their lives, at the same time many are treating it as a scam.

I would like to know whether the Ads.Cash really uses Ethereum contract/blockchain or do Ethereum really know about Ads.Cash (which is using Ethereum name)? Is there any alliance between Ethereum and Ads Cash?

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: another MLM scam

Answer (score 1):

A few things to be going on with:

- There's no whitepaper.
- There's no link to a code repository.
- The website is full of jargon that could have been directly copied from any generic blockchain news article.
- There are grammatical and formatting errors on the homepage. (I'm a native English speaker, so this is perhaps an unfair comment. But... at least get someone to proofread it. Cue the comments pointing out my own grammar mistakes... )
- I can't tell if it's just a native Ethereum contract, an ERC-20 token, or a standalone Ethereum clone.
- I can't see the names or faces of anyone involved.
- The icons that link to their social media pages don't work.
- Until I turned off uBlock (which filters out calls to external sources) I effectively couldn't see most of the page.
- When I Googled their parent company - [Clickintensity](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Clickintensity&oq=Clickintensity&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l3j69i60.405j0j4&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - half of the links had the word "scam" in them...

---

So...

> I would like to know whether the Ads.Cash really uses Ethereum
>   contract/blockchain...?

Your guess is as good as anyone else's.

> or do Ethereum really know about Ads.Cash (which is using Ethereum name)?

I sincerely doubt it. Anyone can clone the code and say theirs is an "Ethereum-based chain".

> Is there any alliance between Ethereum and Ads Cash?

I think you can guess the answer to this one :-)

Comment: you will get more details about this scam in http://behindmlm.com/companies/click-intensity-collapsing-plans-ads-cash-coin-pump-dump-relaunch/

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions one by one:

> I would like to know whether the Ads.Cash really uses Ethereum contract/blockchain

Ads.cash is ERC-20 token deployed on ethereum blockchain.

> do Ethereum really know about Ads.Cash

Ethereum doesn't need to know about all the tokens deployed on the blockchain. It's not like that you have to take permission from anyone to deploy a coin on ethereum blockchain.

> Is there any alliance between Ethereum and Ads Cash?

You are confusing coins with organizations. There are no official links available to such partnership. Also, there is no need to have the alliance to deploy a coin or even to fork ethereum project and develop your own blockchain. [Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/) is an open source project.

To ask your further doubts, it will be better to contact the support team of Ads.Cash.

Comment: Aha - you found more than I did :-) Do you have a link to the source that says this is an ERC-20 token, rather than a chain clone?

Comment: Ads.cash is ERC-20 token deployed on ethereum blockchain prove it or edit your answer